# What is the cause of this Azure Portal error?

Tags: azure-functions

I had the portal open to an Azure Function app blade, and this error popped up:

```
Error:

We are unable to reach your function app (Unauthorized). Please try again later. 

Session Id: 721344329a2d472487acaf5be086599a

Timestamp: 2017-02-10T19:58:31.056Z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens if you've set your functions to require authentication. It's apparently a known issue and being worked on: [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/AzureFunctionsPortal/issues/794)

The screenshot in the post shows another error that you'll see as well.

In my personal experience, since I also have authentication enabled, this has prevented me from using the "Monitor" tab on a function: it just sits there and stays in the "Loading..." state forever. If I disable authentication, all works as expected. You may also find that you can't test your functions in-portal since authentication is on.

I wound up not being too inconvenienced by it by switching to locally developing my functions (as well as testing them) and then publishing my functions to the portal via Visual Studio. But it is something that I'd like to see fixed soon.